# Shutdown Button without questions?

Tags: suspend, hibernate

Ubuntu 16.04. I dragged Shutdown Button to desktop. When I double click it, it gives 4 options, lock/suspend/hibernate/shutdown.
The command in the properties is: `gnome-session-quit --power-off`.

How do I change this command to make Ubuntu just shut down the computer, without asking the 4 options? I just want to double click this button and have the system shut down. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out. All I had to do was change the command to: `shutdown -P now`.

To be clear, to put a "shutdown" button on the desktop:

1. type `"shutdown"` in Unity search bar.
2. drag the result shutdown button to the desktop.
3. right click, choose *Properties*, and in command, change it from
   `gnome-session-quit --power-off` to `shutdown -P now`.

Now all you have to do is double click this "shutdown" button on your desktop and Ubuntu immediately shuts down the computer. This works great!